# Check if function is coercive

Tags: optimization, coercive

I am trying to check if the function $U(x,y)=6\ln x+\ln y$ is coercive. I know, that i need to check if $\lim_{\vert (x,y) \vert \rightarrow \infty} U(x,y) = +\infty$, and so far I have

$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow \infty} U(x,y) = +\infty$

$\lim_{ -(x,y)  \rightarrow \infty} U(x,y) = -\infty$

Does this mean that the function is not coercive?

Comment: Why do you consider the case $(x,y)\to 0$ ?

Comment: @zwim that was a typo, I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, but you need to stay in the domain of definition of $U$ which is $D=]0,+∞[×]0,+∞[$.

So you need $||(x,y)||\to+\infty$ only in $D$ for the norm you have chosen.

**WARNING: It is different from $|x|\to+\infty\text{ AND }|y|\to+\infty$**

For instance for $n\in\mathbb N^*$ and $n\to\infty$ we have $||(n,\frac 1{n^6})||\to+\infty$

$U(n,\frac 1{n^6})=6\ln(n)+\ln(\frac 1{n^6})=6\ln(n)-6\ln(n)=0$

Thus $U$ cannot be coercive.

Answer (score 0):

Your function $U$ is only defined for $(x,y)$ with $x>0$ and $y>0$.

For $x \to \infty$ and $y \to \infty$ we have $U(x,y)  \to \infty$.

Comment: Why the downvote ??????